# How do I resolve errors when building OGRE3D from source in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, ogre

How am I to resolve the following errors, having built both OGRE and its only mandatory dependency (FreeType solutions) in CMake from source. FreeType compiles successfully in visual studio 2015, but when I try to compile OGRE it spits out the following errors. Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning C4251   'Ogre::DeflateStream::mCompressedStream': class 'Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::DataStream>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by     clients of class 'Ogre::DeflateStream'    OgreMain    C:\Users\User\Desktop\ogre_src_v1-8-  1\OgreMain\include\OgreDeflate.h  58
Warning C4251   'Ogre::DeflateStream::mReadCache': class 'Ogre::StaticCache<2048>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of  class 'Ogre::DeflateStream'    OgreMain    C:\Users\User\Desktop\ogre_src_v1-8-1\OgreMain\include\OgreDeflate.h    65
Warning C4251   'Ogre::DeflateStream::mTempFileName': class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Ogre::DeflateStream'  OgreMain    C:\Users\User\Desktop\ogre_src_v1-8-1\OgreMain\include\OgreDeflate.h    60
Warning C4251   'Ogre::DeflateStream::mTmpWriteStream': class 'Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::DataStream>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Ogre::DeflateStream'  OgreMain    C:\Users\User\Desktop\ogre_src_v1-8-1\OgreMain\include\OgreDeflate.h    59
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory   OgreMain    C:\Users\User\Desktop\ogre_src_v1-8-1\OgreMain\src\OgreDeflate.cpp  32
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\OgreMain.lib' OgrePaging  C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\Components\Paging\LINK  1
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\OgreMain.lib' Plugin_PCZSceneManager  C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\PlugIns\PCZSceneManager\LINK    1
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\OgreMain.lib' OgreMeshUpgrader    C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\Tools\MeshUpgrader\LINK 1
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\OgreMain.lib' OgreRTShaderSystem  C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\Components\RTShaderSystem\LINK  1
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\OgreMain.lib' OgreXMLConverter    C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\Tools\XMLConverter\LINK 1
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\OgreMain.lib' Plugin_BSPSceneManager  C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\PlugIns\BSPSceneManager\LINK    1
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\OgreMain.lib' Plugin_OctreeSceneManager   C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\PlugIns\OctreeSceneManager\LINK 1
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\OgreMain.lib' Plugin_ParticleFX   C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\PlugIns\ParticleFX\LINK 1
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\OgreMain.lib' RenderSystem_GL C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\RenderSystems\GL\LINK   1
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\OgrePaging.lib'   OgreTerrain C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\Components\Terrain\LINK 1
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\Plugin_PCZSceneManager.lib'   Plugin_OctreeZone   C:\Users\User\Desktop\OGRE2\PlugIns\OctreeZone\LINK 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more dependencies than only FreeType. There is an official, dedicated repository that contains everything relevant, including zlib:

https://bitbucket.org/cabalistic/ogredeps

Clone / download that and make sure that OgreMain can see it, e.g. by putting it into a folder named "Dependencies" inside the root of your Ogre source folder. Then it should get picked up by the regular CMake scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Your `OgreMain` project isn't finding the file `zlib.h`.  You need to make sure that you have the dependencies include directory included in OgreMain's include path so that it can locate the `zlib.h` file.

Comment: where would I be able to find zlib.h the only place I've seen a file called z lib would be in the source before i built free-type would that be the one ? thank you once again

Comment: i have added the path to the include paths for the ogre main project

Comment: @BillSimmons Yes `zlib.h` is found in the 'Dependencies\Include` path of your Ogre root source directory.